# Error after installing outbound e-mail

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

While Tridion Upgrade from Tridion 2009 to Tridion 2011 SP1, 
Content Manager, Content Manager Explorer is successfully installed and I was easily able browse the Tridion GUI but when I was trying to install the Outbound e-mail I got the error “SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 has encountered a problem and need to close”.

After checking event viewer ->Application log , I received following error

**“Product: SDL Tridion Audience Manager and Outbound E-mail 2011 SP1 -- Error 25542. Failed to find node: /configuration/tridion.templating/defaultTemplatesScripts in XML file: C:\Program Files\Tridion\config\Tridion.ContentManager.config, system error: -2147020584 “**

After adding the following missing key “defaultTemplatesScripts” in Tridion.ContentManager.config, Outbound e-mail is successfully installed but now **I am not able to browse the Tridion GUI**, getting Javascript error :

```
            <defaultTemplatesScripts>
            <defaultTemplatesScript scriptFile="SetupDefaultTemplates.xml"/>
            <defaultTemplatesScript scriptFile="SetupOutboundEmailTemplates.xml"/>
            </defaultTemplatesScripts>
```

Webpage error details

```
Message: Syntax error
Line: 3
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: /WebUI/Editors/CME/Views/Dashboard/Dashboard_v6.1.0.55920.5_.aspx?mode=js
```

Message: 'Tridion' is undefined

```
Line: 1
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: /WebUI/Core/stringresources.js
```

Answer (score 3):

The error is actually windows stopping the installer process because it did a boo boo.
Unfortunately this means the installer could not rollback the installation and your stuck with  an incompletely installed outbound e-mail. (part of the install process is adding configuration nodes,thats why Tridion is complaining about the missing configuration)

Try running the installer again, de-installing the Outbound E-mail part and then trying to install it again. 
you probably need to do a reboot between the de- and the re-install

Answer (score 3):

As Gertjan suggested you may need to reboot between the de-install and re-install and at the end as well after re-install.

It should work after this.